# Javascript on throw event?

Tags: javascript, events, plugins, throw

Is there a way in Javascript to listen to on throw events?

I want to be able to have an event handler be called even when code like this is executed:

```
var hi = "hi";
try {
  throw hi;
}
catch (e) {

}
```

In chrome (and maybe firebug too) you can run this code and hit "break on all errors" and it will break on that throw line. How exactly are they doing that? Is that outside of Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How they are doing that is the JavaScript engine doesn't continue over errors, it crashes on all error, like if you compiling c++, it is not a language feature, its the browser

Answer (score 0):

That's not event that's exception, the handler goes in the catch-block:

```
try {
    //....
}
catch (e) {
    // exception handling here
    // or may be fire/trigger some event here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer you accepted is not correct.

If you have an error that happens not within `try {} catch() {}` block, then the JavaScript execution will really break at that point.

However, if you wrap your possibly breaking code in `try {} catch() {}`, you can use re-`throw` the error to be handled by one global event handler:

```
window.onerror = function (error) {
  // access `error` object
};

try {
  // for example try to assign property to non-existing object
  undefinedObj[property] = 1;
}
catch (error) {
  // `error` object will be available in `onerror` handler above
  throw new Error(error);
}
```